# Create permutations then ensure each item was used at least once in Python

Tags: python, permutation

I have n items. Each item has an associated value to it. From the n items, I need to create k permutations of r=4 items with the constraint the associated value must be within 1 order of magnitude.

On top of that, I want to "ensure" that most of the n items are used at least once. this is where I'm struggling.

The items are rows in a dataframe What I have so far:

```python
#random starting points
starting_points = np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=(1000)).astype(float)

permutations = []

for p in starting_points:
    # filter by range
    min = p - 0.5
    max = p + 0.5
    options = items[items['value'].between(min, max)]
    if len(options) >=4:
        choices_df = options.sample(n=4)
        permutation = {}
        for i in range(4):
            permutation["id {}".format(i+1)] = choices_df['id'].iloc[i] 
        permutations.append(permutation)
```

I generate random starting points (1000), then define a range from which items can be chosen and sample 4 items. This works to generate about 1000 random permutations given the constraints. However, if I only need say 30 permutations how can I ensure that most of the items are chosen at least once?

Comment: You mean you want to generate *combinations* (not *permutations*)? Also, how is `input_table_1` defined? It seems that for `k` combinations of length `r` you can select at most `k*r` distinct elements, so if `len(input_table) > k*r` then this seems to contradict your requirements.

Comment: I am not completely following the question - if you make 30 permutations of 4 items each, that would, in the best case, have 120 different items. You will not be able to pick most of the 1000 items in the 30 permutations at all

Comment: @Mortz there are n items not 1000. You are right that what you say could be an issue but it's not. there is enough slots for each item to be used once.

Comment: @beginner_ Please share the definition of `df` and `items` so that your code becomes complete and reproducible.

Comment: sry that was an anonymization issue. there is only items with columns id and value.

Comment: @beginner_ You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (that includes the definition of `items`) and explain the expected output. Otherwise it's difficult to assess what exactly the problem with your code is and how to solve it.

Comment: @a_guest it's a question about a general algorithm not a specific piece of code

Comment: @beginner_ It's about making the problem as clear as possible, in such a way that others can understand what exactly you are asking. As your questions stands, this is not the case. Improving your question by including a fully reproducible example will greatly increase the chances of receiving an answer. So I suggest you include an example definition of `items`, then show the output that you obtain with your algorithm and explain what's wrong with that output and what you would like to achieve instead.